# "hundreds of years" or "hundred years"

Tags: word-meaning, numbers

**Second  to  KL  in  size  are  the  historic  trading  cities  of  Melaka  and  Penang,  with  buildings dating  back  hundreds  of  years.**

If I wan to say the age of buildings in Melaka and Penang,

> 1.Buildings in Melaka and Penang are **hundreds of years old.**
>
> 2.Buildings in Melaka and Penang are **hundred years old.**

I want to know whether "hundreds of years" and "hundred years" are the same in meaning.

Answer (score 4):

> hundreds of years old

This means the exact age is not known. But it is in the order of hundreds of years. It can be one hundred, or many hundreds, for all I care.

> hundred years old

This means that the age is exactly 100 years. Note that it is a subset of the other one.

Clearly, both of these have different meanings.